# Using Pnp Modren search webpart how to restrict the search of the users for particular site collection instead of global search to get the results fro

Tags: pnp-js

How to restrict the pnP people search to particular site collection instead of global search,so that it can pull the users from that site collection only while searching
in the Query temaplate tried Path:"site collection URL" and MemberShipId:0